# Oracle SQL Help Data Totals

Tags: sql, oracle

I am on Oracle 12c and need help with the simple query.

Here is the sample data of what I currently have:

```
Table Name: customer
```

Table DDL

```
create table customer(
    customer_id    varchar2(50),
    name           varchar2(50),
    activation_dt  date,
    space_occupied number(50)
    );
```

Sample Table Data:

```
customer_id  name     activation_dt  space_occupied 
abc          abc-001  2016-09-12                 20
xyz          xyz-001  2016-09-12                 10
```

Sample Data Output

The query I am looking for will provide the following:

```
customer_id  name     activation_dt  space_occupied
abc          abc-001  2016-09-12                 20
xyz          xyz-001  2016-09-12                 10
Total_Space  null     null                       30
```

Comment: Are you looking to format the output of query to add an extra row that adds space_occupied from 1st 2 rows to give (10+20). If that's the case, are you trying to display it as a table on any front end

Comment: Please edit your question to show your best effort so far and what went wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a bit unusual, as if customer_id is integer, then you have to cast it to string etc, but it this is your requirement, then if be achieved this way.

```
SELECT customer_id,
       name,
       activation_dt,
       space_occupied
FROM
  (SELECT   1   AS seq,
                customer_id,
                name,
                activation_dt,
                space_occupied
   FROM customer

    UNION ALL 

   SELECT 2             AS seq,
    'Total_Space'       AS customer_id,
    NULL                AS name,
    NULL                AS activation_dt,
    sum(space_occupied) AS space_occupied
   FROM customer
   )
ORDER BY seq
```

Explanation:

- Inner query:

  - First part of union all; I added `1 as seq` to give `1`
    hardcoded with your resultset from customer.
  - Second part of union
    all: I am just calculating sum(space_occupied) and hardcoding other
    columns, including `2 as seq`
- Outer query;     Selecting the data
  columns and order by seq, so `Total_Space` is returned at last.

Output

```
    +-------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
    | CUSTOMER_ID |  NAME   | ACTIVATION_DT | SPACE_OCCUPIED |
    +-------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
    | abc         | abc-001 | 12-SEP-16     |             20 |
    | xyz         | xyz-001 | 12-SEP-16     |             10 |
    | Total_Space | null    | null          |             30 |
    +-------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Utsav this worked the only thing though for some odd reason I needed to change was to cast the space_occupied column into to a to_number in the data that i recieved their were decimals and nulls so the to_number did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly hack-y approach to this, using  the grouping function `ROLLUP()`. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions080.htm#SQLRF00647).

```
SQL> select coalesce(customer_id, 'Total Space') as customer_id
  2         , name
  3        , activation_dt
  4        , sum(space_occupied) as space_occupied
  5  from customer
  6  group by ROLLUP(customer_id, name, activation_dt)
  7  having grouping(customer_id) = 1
  8  or (grouping(name) + grouping(customer_id)+ grouping(activation_dt)) = 0;

CUSTOMER_ID  NAME         ACTIVATIO SPACE_OCCUPIED
------------ ------------ --------- --------------
abc          abc-001      12-SEP-16             20
xyz          xyz-001      12-SEP-16             10
Total Space                                     30

SQL>
```

`ROLLUP()` generates intermediate totals for each combination of column; the verbose `HAVING` clause filters them out and retains only the grand total.

Comment: +1, I always learn something new here. Just read about [Rollup](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets) and it seems that it is made only for this kind of situations. Nice read.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a great place to use `group by grouping sets` seems like this is what they were designed for. [Doc link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm#i1006842)

```
SELECT coalesce(Customer_Id,'Total_Space') as Customer_ID
     , Name
     , ActiviatioN_DT
     , sum(Space_occupied) space_Occupied
FROM customer
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Customer_ID, Name, Activation_DT, Space_Occupied)
                       ,())
```

The key thing here is we are summing space occupied.  The two different grouping mechanisms tell the engine to keep each row in it's original form and 1 records with space_occupied summed; since we group by () empty set; only aggregated values will be returned; along with constants (coalesce hardcoded value for total!)

[image]

The power of this is that if you needed to group by other things as well you could have multiple grouping sets.  imagine a material with a product division, group and line and I want a report with sales totals by division, group and line.  You could simply group by () to get grand total, (product_division, Product_Group, line) to get a product line (product_Divsion, product_group) to get a product_group total and (product_division) to get a product Division total.  pretty powerful stuff for a partial cube generation.